# Nesting Vue components with v-for versus HTML/JavaScript logic?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, reactive-programming

I have  this `v-for` loop:

```
<truchet-tile v-for="tile in tiles" v-bind:key="tile.id" :id="tile.id" :ttype="tile.ttype">
  </truchet-tile>
```

I want to put `<div>` tags around each *row* of tiles, so that the rows aren't inline like they are now:
[image]

I could create a new Vue component called `rowOfTiles`, and loop on that with a nested `v-for` for the tile components in each row.

1. Is it possible, instead, to apply a simple nested loop logic to the tiles and rows of tiles using HTML and JavaScript *without* using DOM methods. Something like this:
   [image: JavaScript logic]
2. If so, in situations like this, is it better practice to trend toward creating additional Vue components or to trend toward finding ways to do things on the "model" side with the data? (E.g. how performance-expensive is it to create new classes of Vue components?)

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/facechomp/hmLae5c8/6/

Comment: I have a large scale SPA with hundreds of components built w/ webpack and it is blazing fast. I am not 100% sure what your question is here you can easily benchmark both methods, however, I think you will find them inconsequential. By creating a clear separation of concerns within your components has many benefits, clear readability of the code as well as the potential for reuse in various places within your app. I would also argue making all of your const reactive & performing that logic beforeMount would be more in line with VUE best practices https://jsfiddle.net/timwickstrom/eqmdt8h0/8/

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com Thank you. Is it even possible to do with HTML and JS (my question #1 above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the concept of a row of tiles, you should have rows of tiles in your data. Then it is straightforward to iterate over them in your template.

Your initialization can be

```
for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  vm.tiles.push([]);
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    // Vue tile component handles reactivity here:
    vm.tiles[y].push({
      id: id,
      ttype: Math.round(Math.random() * 6) // random tile
    });
    id++;
  }
}
```

and your template would have something like

```
  <div v-for="row in tiles">
    <truchet-tile v-for="tile in row" v-bind:key="tile.id" :id="tile.id" :ttype="tile.ttype">
    </truchet-tile>
  </div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kp5jtrm/)